# PL/SQL Printing Cursor Elements

Tags: oracle, plsql, while-loop, cursor

I tried several ways and looked lots of codes, but I couldn't do it. I have 2 tables

```
Declare
   v_ay  varchar2(32);
   cursor c_clone_time is 
     select beko_user_ref 
      from user_role;
begin
   open c_clone_time;
   fetch c_clone_time into v_ay
   WHILE c_clone_time%FOUND LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line (v_ay);
   end while;
end;
```

I'm just trying to print the cursor values, but it is always failing. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several spots(syntactical, semantical, and logical errors) in your code needed attention:

1. Minor one. The `fetch c_clone_time into v_ay` statement not terminated by semicolon `;`.
2. You end `while` as any other loop statement with `end loop;` clause, not `end while` or `end for` as you might think.
3. To be able to print the contents of the cursor and successfully get out of the loop, you need to fetch from that cursor inside the loop as well, otherwise you are stuck with a never-ending loop:

Having said that your code might look look this:

```
declare
  v_ay  varchar2(32);
  cursor c_clone_time is 
    select beko_user_ref 
      from user_role;
begin
  open c_clone_time;
  fetch c_clone_time into v_ay;
  while c_clone_time%found loop
    dbms_output.put_line (v_ay);
    fetch c_clone_time into v_ay;
  end loop;
end;
```

Test case:

```
create table user_role(
  beko_user_ref varchar2(100)
);

insert into user_role(beko_user_ref)
  select dbms_random.string('l', 7)
    from dual
 connect by level <= 7;

commit;
```

Print the cursor:

```
set serveroutput on;
clear screen;

declare
  v_ay  varchar2(32);
  cursor c_clone_time is 
    select beko_user_ref 
      from user_role;
begin
  open c_clone_time;
  fetch c_clone_time into v_ay;
  while c_clone_time%found loop
    dbms_output.put_line (v_ay);
    fetch c_clone_time into v_ay;
  end loop;
end;
```

Result:

```
anonymous block completed
kcjhygy
cgunlmt
ofxaspd
qwqvnxx
nxjdrli
luevaqk
xvdocpr
```

Comment: wow thats fantastic. it is directly worked and did what i wanted. and big thanks for the explanations :)